# Is the phrase "You don’t just sit down and be productive." OK?

Tags: verbs

In the article ["Getting in too-much touch (interruption is not collaboration)"](https://signalvnoise.com/archives2/getting_in_toomuch_touch_interruption_is_not_collaboration.php) there is a phrase that seemed somewhat unnatural to me: "You don’t just sit down and be productive".

What triggered me was the verb "to be". The plural form of this verb is "are". So, shouldn't it be "You don't just sit down and are productive"?

Comment: I agree with you. Maybe an error by the author?

Comment: It could be "You can't ".

Answer (score 1):

The "be" is the bare infinitive form, as it should be.   So is the "sit".   The only verb in a finite form in this sentence is the "do" of the contraction "don't".   That is the only word which agrees with the subject.

There are two infinitive phrases, "[to] sit down" and "[to] be productive".   The conjunction "and" coordinates these two phrases.   The adverb "just" modifies the resulting coordination.

It's possible to analyze this sentence such that "just sit down and be productive" is a modified compound infinitive phrase serving as the direct object of the negated auxiliary verb "don't".   This coordination also happens to be the same form that an imperative compound sentence employs.

Even if your framework rejects the notion that the auxiliary "do" licenses a direct object, you can still find yourself with two separate predicates to analyze: "don't just sit down" and "don't be productive".   The "be productive" phrasing must in some way combine with "you don't".

There is no "you don't are productive" in English.   The two finite forms conflict, instead of combining naturally.